# Can ankane/pgsync perform bidirectional synchronisation?

Tags: pgsync

We have a cluster on Postgres 12 installed locally (CentOS) and another RDS. We want to synchronize two tables, one from on-premise against another from the cloud (RDS), but we need it to be in both directions, that is, local-> RDS and RDS -> local.

The idea is to be able to attack (insert/update/delete) indistinctly from the applications to one or another cluster.
Can ankane/pgsync be used to update tables bi-directionally, or is it one-way parent/child mode?
Is this possible with pgsync (ankane) or is there another tool?